# I'm not getting how this output is coming.Can anyone explain me the output of this programme?

Tags: java

[image]

when put 08 in array then it shows a error `"The literal 08 of type int is out of range"`

Comment: [Java Octal Literals tutorial](http://www.javacjava.com/OctalLiterals.html).

Comment: I just goggle for 'java 08' and got the answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

Integer literals starting with `0` in Java are parsed as octal, and 0-7 are the only valid [octal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).